# What tags are associated with the non-tools/software side of graphic design?

Tags: discussion

As [this question](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/it-this-page-really-about-graphic-design) pointed out, there's apparently been a slight slant in the content on GD.SE towards more tools and applications questions. For instance, there are almost twice as many questions tagged [adobe-photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) as the next most popular tag (which is [adobe-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator)). This focus on tools and software has been mentioned before as problematic. The problem is not that those questions are naturally bad, or off-topic or unhelpful, but that they are overwhelming the site. I want to try to change that, starting with those of you who participate on Meta.

I would like to start running something similar to the **Topic of the Week** contests that have been done [on](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1296/discontinued-weekly-topic-contest-ask-great-questions-enter-to-win-a-prize) [other](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/its-plato-week) [sites](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/topic-of-the-week-contest-updated-august-29). Instead of focusing on a single topic/tag, the contest **would focus on a number of tags**, all of which expand the scope of the site and will **diversify the home page** to one that looks less like **Adobe.SE** and more like **Graphic Design.SE**.

I'm not the foremost expert on graphic design, so I would like to know what tags we want expanded to diversify the content here. Using the aforementioned Meta post, I would assume that the following are viable selections:

- [composition](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition)
- [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography)
- [page-layout](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-layout)
- [color-theory](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-theory) (guessing with this one)

Are those good candidates? Did I miss any more obvious ones? I'm willing to track between 5-8 tags for this. Let's be proactive about diversifying the questions being asked.

Comment: I believe `[color-theory]` would be part of the group. Maybe also [design-principles](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-principles) would fit? I think a big part of what would help is if more of these conceptual tags had wikis and excerpts.

Comment: Something along the lines of logos, identity, and/or branding could work.

Answer (score 4):

I like the 4 posted tags.

Here are a few more tags which may relate more to "theory" rather than tools....

- minimalism
- motion
- proximity
- equilibrium
- similarity
- juxtaposition
- discourse
- psychology
- eye movement

Then there's Nouveau, Deco, modern, contemporary, etc.

Comment: +1 I was thinking when I saw this question that we needed a tag that covered questions about design/art styles such as minimalism, contemporary, etc. Glad I'm not the only one wanting to see content like that. Any ideas on what the umbrella tag could be called? The existing "style" tag has various uses, "design-styles" feels vague, "design-movements" feels a bit pretentious... maybe 'design-styles-movements' is best to snare the most relevant autocompletes? (unrelated: browsing this lead me to discover our old little-used 'style-identification' tag, interesting stuff...)

Comment: art-appreciation? art-history? design-movements doesn't seem pretentious to me and fits well.