# Scope Expansion Project (UPDATE Jan. 21 - Hiatus)

Tags: discussion

**UPDATE (1/21/13):** The Scope Expansion Project has come to its end, but after having made a noticeable, positive impact on the site. There has been a noticeable increase in questions about topics like typography, which have helped diversify the site. And the site is attracting more active users (both visiting and participating) than ever before. Now it's time to let the community stand on its own! It's entirely possible that the project can return at a future time, though, if the community needs this special type of help.

Thanks to everyone who participated!

---

This was done in hopes that it would help add a healthy dose of theory and academic questions in addition to the tools and application questions that are already predominately found on this site.

Previous reading on this matter can be found **[here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/413/it-this-page-really-about-graphic-design)**, and then **[here](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/419/what-tags-are-associated-with-the-non-tools-software-side-of-graphic-design)**.

**How it works:** There will be tags (listed below) monitored each week. Each person who [asks a question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to that topic will be eligible to win a prize.

**How to enter:** [Ask a question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) relating to one of the topics below and tag it accordingly. Each question you ask will get you one entry into a random drawing to win one of the following prizes:

- If your country is regularly serviced by an online Amazon store without exorbitant shipping costs, you can choose an item of your choice (under $50 USD)
- If your country is not serviced by an online Amazon store, you will receive a UX.SE and Stack Exchange swag package of exclusive merchandise.

The difference in prizes is due to the difference in cost for us to ship to various parts of the world.

The question must have a score of 0 or greater and not be closed or deleted to be eligible. **Users may only win once in a four week period.**

**Winners will be selected every Monday at 2PM UTC**.

Eligible questions also tagged [adobe-photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) or [adobe-illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator) are ineligible for the contest. This is because the goal of the Scope Expansion Project is to create questions *other* than ones about software.

**Choosing the tags:** If you have suggestion for tags to be included future topic, please leave them as answers or comments to this post. Similarly if you think any tags should be removed due to lack of usefulness or appropriateness, leave that information as well.

---

**Current Tags:**

- [composition](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition)
- [typography](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/typography)
- [page-layout](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/page-layout)
- [color-theory](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color-theory)
- [logo](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logo)
- [identity](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identity)
- [branding](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/branding)
- [workflow](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workflow)
- [proximity](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proximity) - needs to be created and a tag wiki before tag is eligible
- [juxtaposition](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/juxtaposition) - needs to be created and a tag wiki before tag is eligible
- [design-process](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-process)

---

**Winners:**

- Oct. 8th: **[user568458](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3327/user568458)** - [Typography question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10778)
- Oct. 15th: **[Andy](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/7218/andy)** - [Page Layout question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11029/advice-on-what-to-put-on-my-home-page)
- Oct. 22nd: **[Brendan](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5489/brendan)** - [Typography/Page Layout question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11094/baseline-grid-vs-readability)
- Oct. 29th: [**F'x**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/2415/fx) - [Typography question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11342/how-does-random-choice-of-alternate-characters-work-in-opentype-fonts)
- Nov. 5th: **[Aaron Lang](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5105/aaron-lang)** - [Typography question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11476/how-to-control-word-spacing-in-justified-text-with-css)
- Nov. 12th: **No winner** - No questions met eligibility
- Nov. 19th: **[Joe](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/2913/joe)** - [Typography question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12761/first-word-of-one-page-is-repeated-at-the-end-of-the-previous-page)
- Nov. 26th: **[Oscar](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/8685/oscar)** - [Typography question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12816/is-this-an-effect-or-a-type-of-font)
- Dec. 3rd: **[Maarten](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/7160/maarten)** - [Typography question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/does-hyphenation-increase-legibility)
- Dec. 10th: **[Skaught](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3270/skaught)** - [Design Process question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13178/overcoming-creative-blocks-how-to-break-out-of-current-mindsets), *[deferred to](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/scope-expansion-project-update-dec-10#comment1809_422)* **[Fahad](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/6895/fahad)** - [Workflow question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13201/dreamweaver-uploading)
- Dec. 17th: [**naxa**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/7407/naxa) - [Color Theory question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13417/is-there-a-single-text-color-that-is-acceptable-on-both-dark-and-light-backgroun)
- Dec. 24th: **[TCB13](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/9055/tcb13)** - [Page Layout question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/books-on-the-golden-ratio-others-for-webdesign)
- Dec. 31st: **[tohecz](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/6942/tohecz)** - [Typography/Page Layout question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13720/back-matter-numbering)
- Jan. 7th: **[Adam-E](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/470/adam-e)** - [Color theory/Branding question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13819/designing-interesting-looking-websites-in-greyscale-minimal-tones)
- Jan. 14th: **[Reb](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/9348/reb)** - [Typography question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13978/making-a-typeface-should-i-check-if-it-resembles-any-non-free-or-copyrighted-t)
- Jan. 21st: **[calum](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/9435/calum)** - [Logo/Composition question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15139/client-logo-large-dropshadow-and-awkward-angle-looks-terrible-on-any-media)

Comment: To your two questions in the 3rd Oct update - I'd say yes and yes. For the first, I'd say apply it on a case-by-case basis: if it's clearly more about working some software than the theme (e.g. if it was "How do I change fonts in Inkscape?" tagged with typography) then consider quietly redrawing... For the second, yup, definitely so. We've got a few good workflow questions and they're exactly the kind of sage sector wisdom stuff we should encourage.

Comment: Yes and no. If you make the adobe tags eligible users will assume the new tags relate to the application use - diluting the reasoning for the new tags. The same would go for `workflow`. That will just be used for application questions, which I thought was not the point.

Comment: @scott Think you might have misread 'make... ineligible' as 'make... eligible'? The idea is to *exclude* a question like "How to kern in illustrator' tagged with both `typography` and `adobe-illustrator`, so that it would be only questions about these areas in general, and not questions about these areas that actually are specific to one application.

Comment: How do I write a "Tag Wiki"?

Comment: Oh and I think "Composition" and "Page Layout" are redundant

Comment: Who approves tag wiki edits? I made one for workflow a few days ago...

Comment: @Brendan I believe they go into the general edit approval queue?  At any rate, I think I rejected your suggestion for Workflow with a custom message about it being too minor.  A Tag Wiki should be helpful and provide information about the type of questions.  "How you get from start to finish." is a succinct synopsis, but I don't think it's sufficiently helpful on its own.

Comment: That was just the one-liner at the beginning...I had written two paragraphs in the other text box. I edited that stuff down and put it into the excerpt. Hope it fits the requirements better!

Comment: @Brendan Gotcha'.  For some reason the edit queue didn't show that and I only saw the one-liner.  I just approved your edit with the longer body of text.  Sorry for any confusion/frustration caused.

Comment: Thanks! Let's keep expanding the scope! :D

Comment: Congratulations to the other winners and thank you very much for selecting my question as last weeks winner! All very worthy questions and an excellent competition. Just wish I had some answers on my question :')

Comment: @F'x It is still running!

Comment: I was adding tag definitions but proximity and juxtaposition aren't tags yet.

Comment: @Whoever put in the first 'design-process' tag definition (skaught?): Sorry, I proposed a new one that I've been working on for the past 2–3 days…

Comment: Your definition was better ;) I approved it.

Comment: Can we let someone else win this week? I'd rather the prize go to a newer user. Heck, I'm here anyway :) I'll take it if no one else qualified, but if there are others in the running, please give them priority over me.

Comment: I'd like to create tags for juxtaposition and proximity, but it doesn't seem to want to let me. Do I have to ask a question in order to create the tag?

Comment: @BrettWhite - I won in week three...how do we go about redeeming?

Comment: @BrettWhite Hi Brett. We have been talking about adding Art and Illustration (among others) to the scope. Will you be working with us again on the near future? There are some ideas, and I'll definitely be dedicating more time to the site, so it'd be good if we could have you again!